# Sql Query to get total rows and total rows matching specific condition

Tags: mysql

OK, Here is what my table looks like

```
------------------------------------------------
id                     type
-----------------------------------------------
1                      a
2                      b
3                      a
4                      c
5                      c
7                      a
8                      a
------------------------------------------------
```

Now, I need a query that can give me this output...

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
count(*)   |   count(type=a)   | count(type=b)  | count(type=c)
-----------------------------------------------------------------
8                  4                 1               3
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I only know to get the total set using count(*), but how to do the remaining

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
SELECT 
COUNT(*),
COUNT(CASE WHEN type='a' THEN 1 END) as count_a,
COUNT(CASE WHEN type='b' THEN 1 END) as count_b,
COUNT(CASE WHEN type='c' THEN 1 END) as count_c,
FROM table1;

//or you can do 
SELECT type, COUNT(*) 
FROM table1 
GROUP BY type WITH ROLLUP
```

In the latter case you will get results :

a | 4
   b | 1
   c | 3
   null | 8

Comment: argument for `count`. `COUNT` returns the total number of non-null arguments. And `CASE` has default `ELSE NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) Total, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN type='a' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as CountOfA, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN type='b' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as CountOfB, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN type='c' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as CountOfC, 
FROM    Table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*),type
from [TableName]
Group By Type
```

Comment: this gives me horizontal rows